# Когда появляется атрибут disabled, добавлять класс к блоку

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Имеется форма вопросов, где есть кнопка c классом `.forward`, куда человек нажимает чтобы перейти дальше. После того как человек отвечает на все вопросы, кнопка исчезает посредством добавления аттрибута `disabled="disabled"`. Необходимо в этот момент добавлять класс с `display:none;`.

Я брал готовую от стороннего разработчика форму, поэтому условия ее выполнения поменять нельзя.

Как это реализовать?

```
<button disabled="disabled" type="button" name="forward" class="forward">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно обойтись чистым CSS. Псевдокласс `:disabled` используется для применения стиля к заблокированным элементам форм.

```css
.forward:disabled {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<button disabled="disabled" type="button" name="forward" class="forward">Next</button>
```

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы добавлялся сторонний класс, так как disabled="disabled" добавляется в самом конце, так что через css не получится реализовать.

Answer (score 0):

если есть jQuery то очень просто:

```
if($('.forward').attr('disabled') == 'disabled') {
    $('.forward').addClass('<ваш_класс>');
}
```

---

```
attr ( name ) - получает значение атрибута...
attr ( name, value ) - устанавливает значение атрибута...
attr ( object ) - устанавливает значение атрибута...
attr ( name, function() ) - устанавливает значение атрибута...
```

Взято с документации http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

Так же можно не добавлять класс, а просто скрыть елемент

jQuery:

```
if($('.forward').attr('disabled') == 'disabled') {
    $('.forward').hide();
}
```

Если нужно вернуть елемент:

```
if($('.forward').attr('disabled') == 'disabled') {
    $('.forward').show();
}
```